# Альтернатива расширения для safari

Tags: macos, chrome-extension, safari, firefox-extension

В хроме и в файерфоксе есть отличное приложения для перевода [линк](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Выделяем текст, появляется иконка или горячими клавишами кликаем и получаем popup с переводом и возможностью прослушать текст на двух языках. Но вот в сафари данного приложения не нашел и не нашел достойной альтернативы. К примеру [franker](https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=org.ysoldak.safari.franker-YC74FH34F8) не обладает даже половиной функционала. Или же дефолтный маковский словарь переводит только по слову.

Есть ли что то достойное внимания?

Answer (score 3):

Видимо вы плохо искали

1) [igTranslator for Google](https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.add0n.dictionary-2C3W8RZ8ND): можно переводить целые предложения выделив текст + комбинация клавиш (по умолчанию T) или кликнув на иконку в тулбаре

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2)[TranslateMe](https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.github.marekpiechut.translate-H6AP27PW23):  имеет массу настроек на любой вкус. При установке можете столкнутся с проблемой

> This developer's server appears to be busy. Please try again later.

в этом случае качаем с [гитхаба](https://github.com/andy-portmen/Simple-Translate/blob/master/src/dictionary.safariextz?raw=true) и устанавливаем вручную. Больше информации [на оф страничке](http://add0n.com/google-translator.html?version=0.4.0&type=install)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вам возможно подойдет расширение Lingualeo.

Comment: в приложения есть два существеных минуса: оно очень давно не поддерживается  и переводит только одно слово, что успешно умеет делает стандартный словарь.

Comment: @comalex Не соглашусь с вами относительно наличия обоих минусов. Перевод нескольких слов работает по двойному нажатию с shift без нареканий, а основной + использования именно lingualeo - это добавление перевода в изучаемые слова.